# Custom UINavigationBar fails after applicationdidenterbackground

Tags: uinavigationbar, customization

I have custom navigation bar that I created in app delegate as follows

```
- (void) customAppearance
{
    UIImage *customNav = [UIImage imageNamed:@"02_header2.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:customNav forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:frame];  
}
```

It works just fine. However after the application did enter background, and later will enter foreground it fails to load the custom navigation bar. It gives me my navigation bar in size (320,44).

Here is the `appwillenterforeground` method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    UIImage *customNav = [UIImage imageNamed:@"02_header2.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:customNav forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:frame];
}
```

It does not load my custom nav.bar 
Can anybody know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Make sure that you are using iOS 5 simulator because your code is iOS feature...

Comment: I am testing it on the real device..

Comment: Make sure that is iOS 5 supported